# Need Help to Scrape a Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have to scrape a Website. I using phantomjs for this job. So there is a problem. I have to select form dropdown and then scrape the next page. I Don't know how to select a dropdown using Javascript. So AnyOne Can help me out.
E.g We can click of any link using `$('Selector').trigger('click');`
Thank you for you time.

Comment: trigger change if its a select

Comment: Can you give me an Example. ?